# AngularJS ng-repeat array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Is it possible to use `ng-repeat` with an array of arrays?

Here's my view:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <p>{{item}}</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in item.items">{{i}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my controller:

```
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
      [1, 2, 3],
      [4, 5, 6],
      [7, 8, 9]
    ]
  });
```

Here's my Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/b6vRVpUKkhPANNVXkkJL?p=preview

How can I output:

- 1
- 2
- 3

- 4
- 5
- 6

- 7
- 8
- 9

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem lies with this line:

```
<li ng-repeat="i in item.items">{{i}}</li>
```

`item.items` is `undefined` because **`item` is an array**.

You should enumerate `item` instead of `item.items`:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in item">{{i}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here's a working [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/JdnjWBQpIpYm22s0Tjc9?p=preview).

Comment: does someone has an answer for Angular7? `ng-repeat` does nothing, I think the syntax has changed but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 4):

You almost aleady have the result. It's just a little mistake in your second `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <p>{{item}}</p>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="i in item">{{i}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You are already in item in your second `ng-repeat` you don't need `item.items`.

There is the updated plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/aLx05WWzFRVrocmXwr12?p=preview