# unable to repeat collections value using angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was trying to do a webAPI call from AnguarJs. I receive success response "data" object perfectly.When it is passed to HTML page under "ng-repeat" it is not displaying any records.

Following is the one not working

```
        <tr ng-repeat = "cust in Customers">
            <td>{{ cust.CustomerName }} </td>
            <td>{{ cust.CustomerCode }}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.CustomerAmount }}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.ProcessDate }}</td>
        </tr>
```

But if i put in this way it will display the 0th index records

```
<tr ng-repeat = "cust in Customers">
    <td>{{cust[0].CustomerName }} </td>
    <td>{{cust[0].CustomerCode }}</td>
    <td>{{cust[0].CustomerAmount}}</td>
    <td>{{cust[0].ProcessDate }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Note : In the below code i split up files in different javascript files and referred in the main html page.Just for your information.

My Fiddle Link : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8a90xx5/2/)

Please help me in resolve it.

```js
function Utility(){
    this.ApplicationVersion = "0.0.1";
    this.ApplicationName = "AngularJs First Project";
    this.getDate = function () {
        var dt = new Date();
        return dt.toDateString();
    }
    this.IsEmpty = function (value) {
        if (value.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

function Customer(utility) {
    this.CustomerCode = "1001";
    this.CustomerName = "Ragu";
    this.CustomerAmount = 100;
    this.CalculateDiscount = function()
    {
        return 10;
    }
    this.ProcessDate = utility.getDate();

}

function Factory()
{
    return {
        CreateCustomer: function (utility) {
            return new Customer(utility);

        }
    }
 }
 
 /// <reference path="Utility.js" />
/// <reference path="Customer.js" />
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("BindingCode",BindingCode);
myApp.factory("Factory", Factory);
myApp.service("UtilityObj", Utility);
function BindingCode($scope, UtilityObj, Factory,$http)
{
    $scope.Customer = Factory.CreateCustomer(UtilityObj);
    $scope.Customers = [];
    $scope.Utility = UtilityObj;
    $scope.Customer.CustomerCode = "1002";
    $scope.Customer.CustomerName = "Raman";
    $scope.Customer.ProcessDate = UtilityObj.getDate();
    $scope.Color = "blue";
    $scope.$watch("Customer.CustomerAmount", function () {
        if ($scope.Customer.CustomerAmount < 1000) {
            $scope.Color = "Red";
        }
        else {
            $scope.Color = "Green";
        }
    });
    $scope.Submit = function()
    {
        debugger
        if ($scope.Utility.IsEmpty($scope.Customer.CustomerAmount)) {
            debugger
            
            $http.post("http://localhost:61860/api/Customer", $scope.Customer).then(function(data){
                $scope.Customers = data;
                debugger
                    $scope.Customer = {}; // clearing the record
            },
            function(data)
            {
                debugger
                alert("inside error http call" + data);
            }
            );
            
            //$http.post("http://localhost:61860/api/Customer", $scope.Customer).
            //    success(function (data) {
            //    debugger
            //    $scope.Customers = data;
            //    $scope.Customer = {};
            //});
        }
        else {
            alert("No Proper Date");
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Customer.js"></script>
<script src="Utility.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="CustScreen" ng-controller="BindingCode">
        CustomerCode : <input type="text" ng-model="Customer.CustomerCode" id="txtCustomercode" /> <br />
        CustomerName : <input type="text" ng-model="Customer.CustomerName" id="txtCustomerName" /> <br />
        CustomerDate : <input type="text" ng-model="Customer.ProcessDate" id="txtCustomerDate" /> <br />
        CustomerAmount : <input type="text" style="background-color:{{ Color }}" ng-model="Customer.CustomerAmount" id="txtCustomerAmount" /><br />
        <br />
        {{ Customer.CustomerCode }} <br />
        {{ Customer.CustomerName }} <br />
        {{ Customer.ProcessDate }}<br />
        {{ Customer.CustomerAmount}} <br />
        <input type="submit" ng-click="Submit()" id="Submit" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>Code</td>
                <td>Amount</td>
                <td>ProcessDate</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat = "cust in Customers">
                <td>{{cust.CustomerName }} </td>
                <td>{{cust.CustomerCode }}</td>
                <td>{{cust.CustomerAmount}}</td>
                <td>{{cust.ProcessDate }}</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
</div>      
</body>
```

Comment: the point of jsfiddle is to reproduce your problem. Not just pasting the same code as in the question. You will have to include the minimal necessary code from your other files, and possibly loading angular from an external source. Can you show us how the json returned from your backend looks like ? It looks like every cust item is an array - are you returning an array of arrays?

Comment: you can also change the included js order and try it. and where is angular.min.js in your code??

Comment: this can help you i guess..
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748612/angularjs-ng-repeat-array-of-arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31748612/angularjs-ng-repeat-array-of-arrays)

Comment: I stripped out all of the extra stuff, but here's an example of it working with ng-repeat.

https://jsfiddle.net/6u59q7b7/

Comment: Hi Ganzalo, i am new to angular and jsfiddle. I am not sure how the c# (ASP.Net WEB aPI) code will be taken into consideration in fiddle. That's why for better understanding i pasted the code there.

Comment: Hi coderwill, anuglar.min.js is referred in local.I used VS2015 for the development environment. Downloaded the angular.min.js file to local project folder and referred from there. I changed the order also but no use

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, following is the response captured from browser developer tools -console window.
=========================
config:Object
data:Array(3)
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
length:3
__proto__:Array(0)
headers:function (name)
status:200
statusText:"OK"

Answer (score 0):

Try this
$scope.Customers=data[0];

Comment: i tried "$scope.Customers = data[0];" but still it is not listing

Comment: I don't know why the following is not working 

        <tr ng-repeat = "cust in Customers">
            <td>{{ cust.CustomerName }} </td>
            <td>{{ cust.CustomerCode }}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.CustomerAmount }}</td>
            <td>{{ cust.ProcessDate }}</td>
        </tr>
But if i put in this way it will display the 0th index records

<tr ng-repeat = "cust in Customers">
    <td>{{cust[0].CustomerName }} </td>
    <td>{{cust[0].CustomerCode }}</td>
    <td>{{cust[0].CustomerAmount}}</td>
    <td>{{cust[0].ProcessDate }}</td>
 </tr>

Comment: Can you post here what you are getting as 'data'  from $http ?